# SPSS Count function advice

Tags: probability, spss

Im having some issues with some SPSS code. Im new to SPSS and still trying to figure out the syntax. I'm trying to get my code to count the sum of two dice equal to 7. I cant get the count function to work the way I want it. Below is my code. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #I=1 TO 100000.
COMPUTE case = 1.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE Dice_1 = TRUNC (RV.UNIFORM(1,7)).
COMPUTE Dice_2 = TRUNC (RV.UNIFORM(1,7)).
COMPUTE total = Dice_1+Dice_2. 
COMPUTE Number_Sum7= Dice_1+Dice_2 = 7.
COUNT Num= case TO Number_Sum7(1).
SAVE outfile = 'my file path'.
```

Answer (score 1):

`count` function counts across a list of variables, in each line separately.
What you seem to be looking for is to count over rows.
You can start with:

```
frequencies total.    /* see counts of all possible totals.  
means Number_Sum7/cells=sum.   /* count only the cases where total=7.
```

These will give you the answers in the output window.

If you want the answers in data for further analysis, look up the `aggregate` function.

For example, the following will give you the same results but in a new datasets:

```
DATASET NAME ORIG.
DATASET DECLARE freqs.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='freqs' /BREAK=total /Mycount=N. 
DATASET ACTIVATE ORIG.
DATASET DECLARE only7.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='only7' /BREAK= /only7=sum(Number_Sum7).
```

Or, instead, you can add the results to your present data:

```
AGGREGATE   /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES   /BREAK=total   /TotalCount=N.
AGGREGATE   /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES   /BREAK=   /total7=sum(Number_Sum7).
```